How to override default Log4j xml configuration file name?
We're in the process of migrating applications from a standard tomcat instance to one running in a container that uses ELK for log management. We have jobs that deploy properties (including our log4j.xml config file) from a Git repo to appropriate folder for the servers. Due to differences in how logs are managed between the two systems, we need difference configurations for Log4j. I'm wondering if I can add a separate copy of the config (called say "log4j-container.xml") to the repository and add a VM arg to the command/script that starts tomcat to tell Log4j to use that file rather than the default log4j.xml file (that will also be there and should be ignored). Does such an arg/property exists, or is there a better way to accomplish my goal?

You should probably be using log4j2. When you do, it's -Dlog4j2.configurationFile=/foo/bar/log4j2.xml

Upgrading to log4j2 will be a separate effort. Would this not work with Log4j 1?

Try -Dlog4j.configuration=/foo/bar/log4j2.xml

@g00se: can you post your comment as an answer?

Will do. So I take it the second one worked?

AFAIK:
Log4j 1.x: -Dlog4j.configuration=/foo/bar/log4j.xml
Log4j 2.x: -Dlog4j2.configurationFile=/foo/bar/log4j2.xml

We tried this with our path to "log4j-container.xml", however it still took the config from the log4j.xml file instead. Our plan is to have our admin update his deployment script for properties to overlay the contents of log4j.xml with log4j-container.xml.

How did you pass it?

UPDATE: just tried this myself and it worked fine

Did you have a log4j.xml file with different configuration next to log4j-container.xml to verify that it was only loading config from log4j-container.xml?

"Next to"? I'll raise you to: in the classpath ;)
